# Woocommerce two paypal accounts

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I need to connect two paypal accounts two my store, based on some condition. I found out about `woocommerce_paypal_args` but it doesn't do my job.
i tried something like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_args' , 'uploadwp_override_paypal' );

function uploadwp_override_paypal( $paypal_args, $order ) {
    if (condition) {
         $paypal_args['business'] = 'mail1@paypal.com';
     } else {
         $paypal_args['business'] = 'mail2@paypal.com';
      {
    return $paypal_args;
}
```

But this way I can't change Paypal Api credentials. Is there a way to change credentials, so that I can link two paypal business accounts to my store?

Comment: Hi Nikola - are API creds required because you can just use the emailID?

Comment: Yes i figured it out last night. Turns out i just need business mail.

Comment: Yup, sounds right. Good deal, glad you got it.